# Get an object's position in another object's coordinate system

Tags: python, maya, mel

Is there a way in MEL or Python in Maya to get one object's position in the coordinate system of another object? I have a camera in a scene that may be rotated in any direction and am trying to measure the distance in its local Z axis to the vertices of various objects in the scene. This obviously needs to be fast, since it will likely be run thousands of times across the scene.

In Maxscript the command would be something like

```
" in coordsys $camera "
```

but I have yet to find something like this in Maya. If there's no direct command to do this, does anyone have a way to calculate it using matrix math?

Comment: are you trying to find objects in camera frustum ?

Comment: Determining if the object is inside of the camera frustrum is not necessary for my application, I just need to find out how far (in the camera's local z) the object or vertex is from the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one liner similar to the MXS idiom -- and no easy way to do it in *mel*.  However in Python you can do this fairly easily.

First you need to get the matrix for the coordinate system you want as an `MMatrix`, which is part of the OpenMaya api.  Then get the position you want to check as an MPoint, which is another api class.   Here's the cheap way to get them (there are faster methods but they're much wordier):

```
from maya.api.OpenMaya import MVector, MMatrix, MPoint
import maya.cmds as cmds

def world_matrix(obj):
    """'
    convenience method to get the world matrix of <obj> as a matrix object
    """
    return MMatrix( cmds.xform(obj, q=True, matrix=True, ws=True))


def world_pos(obj):
    """'
    convenience method to get the world position of <obj> as an MPoint
    """
    return MPoint( cmds.xform(obj, q=True, t=True, ws=True))
```

Once you have the matrix and the point, the relative position is simply point times the inverse of the matrix:

```
relative_position = world_pos('pSphere1') * world_matrix('pCube1').inverse()
print relative_position
# (0.756766, -0.0498943, 3.38499, 1)
```

The result will be an MPoint, which has *4* numbers (x, y, z and w); the 4th will always be 1 so you can just ignore it, although the math needs it to account for scales and shears.

Comment: Thanks, thats great. And the explanation is very helpful, I haven't done much OpenMaya scripting yet. Are there any resources online for using it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this MEL script to calculate the distance from `camera1` to `nurbsSphere1` primitive:

```
vector $p1 = `getAttr camera1.translate`;
vector $p2 = `getAttr nurbsSphere1.translate`;
vector $result = $p1 - $p2;
print (mag($result))
```

Printed result must be like this:

```
# MEL 40.1965
```

Or use this Python script to calculate the distance from `camera1` to `nurbsSphere1` primitive:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import math

distance = math.sqrt(pow((float)(cmds.getAttr("nurbsSphere1.tx") - cmds.getAttr("camera1.tx")),2) + 
                     pow((float)(cmds.getAttr("nurbsSphere1.ty") - cmds.getAttr("camera1.ty")),2) + 
                     pow((float)(cmds.getAttr("nurbsSphere1.tz") - cmds.getAttr("camera1.tz")),2) )
print(distance)
```

Printed result must be like this:

```
# Python 40.1964998512
```

Comment: This measures the distance from one object to another, right? That's not quite what I need unfortunately. I need to find out the sphere's translation coordinates (specifically its Z position) in the camera's coordinate system.

Comment: Use this link to dive into the topic: http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-1072860.html
It's advanced topic.